# Print MOXy generated XML before sending the output to JAX-RS Web Service client

Tags: java, eclipselink, jax-rs, moxy

How to print the XML generated by MOXy when using it on the server side to print the XML before sending the XML to the RESTful Web Service client.

```
   @GET
   @Path("/sma")
   @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
   public Representation getRepresentation() throws Exception 
   {
        Representation rep= new Representation ();
        rep.setFirstName("first name");
        rep.setLastName("last name");
        return rep;

   }
```

In the above want to print the representation object XML before sending it to the Web Service client.

Comment: Any help here is appreciated...